# C++ pre-allocated vector of objects containing pointer

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following structure:

```
struct CacheNode {
  set<int> *value;
  int timestamp;
  CacheNode() : value(new set<int>()), timestamp(0) {}
};
```

And I pre-allocate a vector of them as follows:

```
vector<CacheNode> V(10);
```

When I do this, every `CacheNode` element in the vector points to the same `set<int>` in its `value` field. In particular,

```
  V[0].value->insert(0);
  cout << V[1].value->size() << endl;
```

prints out `1` instead of the `0` that I want.

What is the correct way to pre-allocate the vector (or to declare the structure) so that each `CacheNode` have its own `set<int>` instance?

(Note: I do need the `value` to be a pointer to a set, because it is possible in my application for some CacheNodes to share sets.)

Comment: If you want to share objects like that, you should use `shared_ptr`s unless you have a good reason not to. It makes everything much simpler and reduces the risk of memory leaks.

Comment: @Antimony, `shared_ptr` does seem to be useful here. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have violated the rule of 3.  You have created an object with a non-trivial constructor, and failed to create a destructor or copy constructor or `operator=`.

`std::vector<blah> foo(10)` creates a single default constructed `blah`, and makes 10 copies of it in `foo`.  Because you violated the rule of 3, these 10 copies are all identical.

The easiest method would be to do away with the `new`:

```
struct CacheNode {
  std::set<int> value;
  int timestamp;
  CacheNode() : value(), timestamp(0) {}
};
```

another route would be to use a `unique_ptr` for lifetime management, and explicitly copy:

```
struct CacheNode {
  std::unique_ptr<std::set<int>> value;
  int timestamp;
  CacheNode() : value(new std::set<int>()), timestamp(0) {}
  CacheNode(CacheNode&&) = default; // C++11 feature
  CacheNode(CacheNode const& other):value(new std::set<int>( *other.value ) ), timestampe(other.timestamp) {}

  CacheNode& operator=(CacheNode const& other) {
    value.reset(new std::set<int>(*other.value));
    timestampe = other.timestamp;
    return *this;
  }
  CacheNode& operator=(CacheNode&& other) = default;
  // no need for ~CacheNode, unique_ptr handles it
};
```

when you want to take the `std::set<int>` out of your `CacheNode`, call `CacheNode().value.release()` and store the resulting `std::set<int>*`.

`std::shared_ptr<std::set<int>>` would allow shared ownership of the `std::set`.

There are other approaches, including making your `vector` store pointers to `CacheNode`, creating `value_ptr<T>` templates that do value semantics, etc.

In C++11, these are relatively easy and safe, because `std::vector` will move things around, and move semantics on a `value_ptr<T>` won't create a new `T`.

I am a bit leery of your plan to have shared `std::set<int>` between different `CacheNode`, because in general that is bad smell -- the ownership/lifetime of things should be clear, and in this case you have some `CacheNode` that own the `std::set<int>` and others that don't (because they share ownership).  A `shared_ptr` can get around this, but often there are better solutions.

Comment: Note that he requires the ability of CacheNodes to share sets. So he'd have to use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Antimony yes, that does cause complications.  With some sharing ownership, and others not, and wanting copy to create a new buffer yet move not, the fragility of the semantics of this class is getting seriously problematic.

Comment: @Yakk, you are right. Sharing the sets among the CacheNodes is probably bad design. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "`std::vector<blah> foo(10)` creates a single default constructed blah, and makes 10 copies of it in foo." <- it seems that this is no longer true in C++11, where the default constructor will actually be called 10 times.

Answer (score 5):

`vector<CacheNode> V(10);` creates an initial `CacheNode` object and then copies it 10 times. So you have 10 identical objects.

You can use [generate_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n):

```
std::vector<CacheNode> v;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 10u, [](){ return CacheNode{}; });
```

Here's an [example program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3d5d954e44d1bbf4570eea32c487285f-61c3814520a8d4318f681038dc4b4da7).

Comment: This is why the Rule of Three is important. Also, you should use smart pointers when feasible.

Comment: So how can I make them non-identical?

Comment: As a problem, lifetime management -- if some `CacheNode` own their `value`, and other's don't, you aren't in a good place.

Comment: @StackedCrooked, I didn't know about `generate_n`. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @Antimony Have you read about the [Rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html)?

Comment: @Stacked I'd never heard that given a name, but that's what I normally do anyway. Using smart pointers makes everything much simpler (though you'll still have to be careful with `weak_ptr`s to break cycles. At least Boost tells you how to lock them safely).

Answer (score -1):

You will want to use `vector.assign(10, CacheNode())` as what your doing is a way of reserving space mostly.

Also you should do what the other ones say, provide virtual destructor and such.